# If $A,B$ sets, what does $A \Delta B$ mean?

Tags: measure-theory, notation

If $A,B$ sets, what does $A \Delta B$ mean?

I am doing exercises in measure theory, sigma algebras, where in one exercise I shall prove that $A \Delta B$ lies in the sigma algebra. But I have never seen this notation before, what does it mean?

Comment: See [Set operations : symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

Comment: As a note, you should use \triangle for symmetric difference, i.e. $A\triangle B$ rather than $A\Delta B$. In the latter case it looks like either $\Delta$ or $\Delta B$ is a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally
$$A\Delta B=(A-B)\cup(B-A)$$
This is called the *symmetric difference*; it is all elements that are in one set or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

It means, by definition:

$$A \Delta B=(A \setminus B) \cup ( B \setminus A).$$